# RoundBorder doesnt work for ScaleImageButton

Tags: codenameone

RoundBorder doesnt work for ScaleImageButton.

```
//it doesnt works
ScaleImageButton leaveButton = new ScaleImageButton(leaveIcon);
leaveButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(
        RoundBorder.create().color(0xffd04b).rectangle(true)
);

//It works
Label leaveButton = new Label(leaveIcon);
leaveButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(
        RoundBorder.create().color(0xffd04b).rectangle(true)
);
```

One more thing how can I make the roundBorder square? There's rectangle() method but are there any other methods for other structures for instance pentagonal, hexagonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoundBorder is always rounded, you are looking for RoundedBorder which is something else.

Both of these won't work with `ScaledImage*` classes which rely on the background style being image. You can wrap that class in a container and give that the style that you want.